# Is SharePoint's ListViewXML syntax based on a standard?

Tags: web-part, caml-query, list-view

Recently I had to change a ListView webpart and noticed the syntax that renders the HTML is not XSLT. Is this syntax documented somewhere?

Example,

```
<IfEqual>
            <Expr1>
                <GetVar Name="BlogPublishedCurrentDate"/>
            </Expr1>
            <Expr2>
                <Column Name="PublishedDate" Format="DateOnly" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
            </Expr2>
            <Then/>
            <Else>
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[<h3 class="ms-PostDate">]]></HTML>
                <Column Name="PublishedDate" Format="DateOnly" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
                <HTML>
                    <![CDATA[</h3>]]></HTML>
                <SetVar Name="BlogPublishedCurrentDate" Scope="Request">
                    <Column Name="PublishedDate" Format="DateOnly" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
                </SetVar>
            </Else>
        </IfEqual>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [CAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_Application_Markup_Language). Here's the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms426449.aspx) reference.